# Passenger 4 & JRuby: setting JRUBY_OPTS

Tags: jruby, passenger, jrubyonrails

I know i can specify the ruby executable to use with passenger_ruby for a particular virtual server, but is there an easy way to specify the JRUBY_OPTS env variable I want to set for that particular executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set any arbitrary environment variables you want. See [section "About environment variables" from the Phusion Passenger manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#about_environment_variables).

Comment: Awesome, the Nginx env directive was just what I was looking for, though it would be really helpful if I could define it on a per virtual host basis so I could tailor the JRUBY_OPTS to each app.